# Do I have to install MSXML for SDL Tridion 2013?

Tags: 2013, infrastructure

Reviewing my installation notes for SDL Tridion 2013 on Windows Server 2012, I don't remember specifically installing MSXML. I know we needed to for 2011 ([Creating a Development VM Part 3 on TridionWorld](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/creating-development-vm-3.aspx)), right before running the Tridion Database Manager tool.

1. Is it MSXML (version 4.0?) needed for 2013?
2. If so, was it installed for me at some point?

Comment: You'll get a warning if you need it when running the db tool.

Comment: Tridion 2013 doesn't have a db tool, they're powershell scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Tridion itself will not need MSXML 4, but given the legacy dependencies on it, it will still be installed - for instance for Legacy XML templates, Event System, etc.

You don't need to install the databases, since this is done via Powershell scripts. The Tridion installer (I believe) will add it to your installation (together with other requirements like C++ runtimes, Java 7 and whatnot).

Comment: I won't need to re-install to check, thanks Nuno! :-) I'll post a new VM guide as 2013 ships.